# ABP Framework with Angular 9+ Material UI design

Tags: angular, angular-material, frameworks, abp

Stay Home and save lives..!

We planning to adopt **"ABP Framework and Angular 9+ Fuse Material Theme"** for our cloud suite enterprise product.

Is it best match ABP Framework with Angular 9+ Fuse Theme?

Is there any tool which can integrate frontend (Angular 9+) and backend (swagger API)? It may reduce development time?

**Questions, if we integrate above framework:**

- Google AI bot for voice conversation enabled in entire product?
- Utilising backend swagger API in iOS and Android Mobile apps?
- Chat (private & group), voice, video conferencing zoom API and UI integration?
- Business intelligent third-party tools integration for dashboard and reporting?
- Document Processing third-party tools integration?

Is there any alternatives for backend framework?

***Note:***

*- We would like to use angular and material UI*

*- Preferred technology ASPNET Core*

Your recommendation always welcome..!

Thanks a lot..!

Comment: abp.io is the best I have ended up for any scale or kind of applications!